# Getting the index of matched value

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-stitch

I've created online cluster in mongodb atlas then created mongodb stitch app, in the stitch javascript editor, how can I get the index of x when match it ? example :

```
{
"_id": 5646546,
"items":[   {"x": 12, "y": 4} ,  {"x": 12, "y": 4}   ]

}
```

so when x= 12 the index should be 0

Comment: So you wanted to write a javascript func ?

Comment: Yes, I use python  so I know a little about javascript

Comment: To explain more , I imported the collection using stitch to goole sheet  and everything is ok what I want know is making the changes in google sheet synced to my database SO I'm gonna make google app script that return the id  and changes > on the stitch side I'm gonna search for id which is the (x) in my example and update y

Answer (score 0):

You can write a javascript function in stitch like below :

```
const getIndex = (inputArray, match) => {
  return inputArray.findIndex(element => element.x == match);
};

let obj = {
  _id: 5646546,
  items: [
    { x: 12, y: 4 },
    { x: 12, y: 4 }
  ]
};

let obj2 = {
  _id: 5646547,
  items: [
    { x: 121, y: 4 },
    { x: 12, y: 4 },
    { x: 122, y: 4 }
  ]
};

console.log(getIndex(obj.items, 12)); // prints 0
console.log(getIndex(obj2.items, 122)); // prints 2
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution , but I'm getting erorr  https://imgur.com/a/aP5QKJ8

Comment: @ManafA.B :  I think issue is at line 17, Remove that, Also do you just need to log response ? You can remove comments *prints* as well..